# TensorFlow CNN: Handling 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' Error with Grayscale Images from .tfrecord Files

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm facing an issue while working on a CNN project. I need to use pre-trained weights from ImageNet for my TensorFlow CNN in order to find keypoints in the training pictures, but I keep encountering the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 1 vs 3
```

This error arises because I'm working with grayscale images loaded from .tfrecord files.
i've looked up online for solutions, but most of them involve converting .jpg or .png images before training. In my case, I'm working with .tfrecord files containing both grayscale images and coordinate data so those solution doesn't work for me.
Here's a simplified code snippet to give you context:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.data import TFRecordDataset
import glob

# Loading training dataset
filenames_train = glob.glob(dir_in_training + "*.tfrecord")
ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filenames_train)
dataset_training = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)
dataset_training = dataset_training.shuffle(5340, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

# Model setup
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
    include_top=False,
    weights='imagenet',
    input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    pooling=None,
    classes=num_classes,
    classifier_activation=None
)

# Training the network
history = model.fit(dataset_training, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size_training, callbacks=callback_list, validation_data=dataset_validation, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

For your reference, here's the full code for my training script, including data loading and model setup.

```
import sys

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.data import TFRecordDataset
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, schedules
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
import New_predict as new_pred
import glob
import cv2  # Aggiunto import per OpenCV
from skimage.color import gray2rgb  # Aggiunto import per convertire immagini grayscale in RGB
import numpy as np


from torch.profiler import schedule

import lib.deserialize_example_cnn as des
import lib.show_keypoints as sk

cnn_name = "error_cnn_name"

def main(version_used,lr_i, bst,opt,loss_input,showSummary):
    global cnn_name
    if version_used == "50":
        cnn_name = "cnn_LR_res50MINI"
    elif version_used == "152":
        cnn_name = "cnn_LR_res152MINI"

    sub_run_id = sk.randomInt(0, 999)
    fs = "->lr_i:" + str(lr_i)  + "  bst:" + str(bst)+ "  opt:"+ str(opt)+"  loss_input:"+ str(loss_input)+"sub_run_id"+str(sub_run_id)

    # parameters
    shape_image = 500
    input_shape = (shape_image, shape_image, 3)
    num_classes = 28
    files_out_names = "last_model_trained.h5"

    if sk.CLUSTER == False:
        dir_in = "C:/risorse/PDL/dataset_dim500/"
        model_path = "C:/risorse/PDL/modeldir/"
    else:
        dir_in = "datadir/dataset_dim500/"
        model_path = "datadir/modeldir/"

    if (sk.CLUSTER == False):
        num_epochs = 2
    else:
        num_epochs = 8
    batch_size_training = bst

    dir_in_training = dir_in + "training/"
    dir_in_validation = dir_in + "validation/"
    dir_in_testing = dir_in + "testing/"

    # loading training dataset
    # print("dir_in_training:"+dir_in_training)
    filenames_train = glob.glob(dir_in_training + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filenames_train)
    dataset_training = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)
    dataset_training = dataset_training.shuffle(5340, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)  # 5340 is the seed

    # Visualizing training images
    xi = 0

    # loading validating dataset
    filename_validate = glob.glob(dir_in_validation + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filename_validate)
    dataset_validation = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)

    # batching data
    dataset_training = dataset_training.batch(batch_size_training)
    print("dataset shape, ",dataset_training)
    dataset_validation = dataset_validation.batch(1)

    # Model definition
    if version_used == "50":
        model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
            include_top=False,
            weights='imagenet',
            input_tensor=None,
            input_shape=input_shape,
            pooling=None,
            classes=num_classes,
            classifier_activation=None
        )
    elif version_used == "152":
        model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet152V2(
            include_top=True,
            weights=None,
            input_tensor=None,
            input_shape=input_shape,
            pooling=None,
            classes=num_classes,
            classifier_activation=None
        )
    else:
        sk.pal("unknown version:" + version_used,cnn_name)
        sys.exit(1)

    if showSummary == True:
        model.summary()

    LROnPlateau = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(
        monitor="val_loss",
        factor=0.1,
        patience=4,
        verbose=1,
        mode="auto",
        min_delta=0.0001,
        cooldown=0,
        min_lr=1e-6,)

    callback_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode="min", patience=2, restore_best_weights=True)
    callback_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(model_path + "model_best_"+ str(cnn_name) +str(sk.RunId)+"_" +files_out_names , monitor='val_loss',mode='min', save_best_only=True)


    if opt == 'adamax':
        optimizer = Adamax(learning_rate=lr_i)
    elif opt == 'adam':
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_i)
    elif opt == 'rmsprop':
        optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=lr_i)
    elif opt == 'adagrad':
        optimizer = Adagrad(learning_rate=lr_i)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid optimizer specified!")

    # Compiling model
    # model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = initial_learning_rate))
    model.compile(loss=loss_input, optimizer=optimizer)

    sk.pal("starting model.fit",cnn_name)
    callback_list = [callback_early_stopping, callback_checkpoint,LROnPlateau]
    # Fit model
    history = model.fit(dataset_training, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size_training, callbacks=callback_list, validation_data=dataset_validation, use_multiprocessing=True)

    # plot graph
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(history.history['loss'])):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(history.history['loss'][i])

    # loading test dataset
    filename_test = glob.glob(dir_in_testing + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filename_test)
    dataset_test = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)

    # batch dataset
    dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(1)

    # Evaluate model on test dataset
    print("Evaluate on Test Dataset")
    eval_loss = model.evaluate(dataset_test)

    sk.pal("Evaluation loss: "+str(eval_loss),cnn_name)

    modelsave(model,model_path + files_out_names)

    eval_mae = 99999 #it have to be placed after model save to be evaluated
    try:
        eval_mae = new_pred.predict_main()
    except Exception as e:
        sk.pal("mae evaluetion fail: "+str(e),cnn_name)

    try:
        m_name = sk.getModelName(model_path+"res50LR", eval_loss, eval_mae, lr_i,bst)
        modelsave(model,m_name)
    except Exception as e:
        sk.pal("modello personalizzato non creato:"+str(e),cnn_name)
    sk.pal("model saved",cnn_name)

    return eval_mae

def modelsave(model_input,location):
    global cnn_name
    try:
        model_input.save(location, save_format='h5')
        sk.pal("model saved successfully at: "+location,cnn_name)
    except Exception as e:
        sk.pal("model save fail. model: "+location+"\nerror: "+str(e),cnn_name)

main("50",0.01, 2,'adam',"mse",False)
```